# Updating a React context: "x is not a function"

Tags: reactjs, constants, react-context

I'm trying to update a React context, and saw this answer.

```
const LanguageSwitcher = () => {
  const { language, setLanguage } = useContext(LanguageContext);
  return (
    <button onClick={() => setLanguage("jp")}>
      Switch Language (Current: {language})
    </button>
  );
};
```

Seems sensible to me, except that I get "setLanguage is not a function". This error actually seems reasonable as setLanguage appears to be declared a constant.

How do these declarations of "const { x, y } = z" work? Am I declaring two constants? If so, why do so many examples I read appear to allow me to treat x as a variable and y as a function? And why am I getting this error?

Sorry, newbie here. Appreciate the help.

EDIT: The context code is:

```
const LanguageContext = React.createContext({
  language: "en",
  setLanguage: () => {}
});
```

Comment: You need to checkout what your context is providing you. 
I'm not sure but you can check this syntax.

`[language, setLanguage] = useContext(LanguageContext)`;

Comment: `How do these declarations of "const { x, y } = z" work? ` It's called a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). It's the same as `const x = z.x; const y = z.y;`. As for why you're getting the error, you'll need to show us `LanguageContext` and where you render a `<LanguageContext.Provider>` to help diagnose that

Comment: yes, though i'm not sure, if your context actually provides data that way.

Comment: It would be better if you could share the context code here

Answer (score 5):

My problem was that I didn't use the context provider component.

I put mine in app.js, or you could do something like this:

```
<LanguageContextProvider>
   <LanguageSwitcher/>
</LanguageContextProvider>
```

Answer (score 0):

First do not forget the wrap your app with the context provider.
Or if you have multiple context they need to be nested upon hierarchy. For example I have 2 different context as UserContext and MessageContext. I 'll need some functions and variables to use in MessageContext from UserContext.
So I wrapped App component in index.js with UserContextProvider. And I wrapped the routes in App.js with MessageContextProvider. So UserContext is at the top that I can get its data to use in other all components and contexts.